# Why getting too many files open error while using subprocess lsusb -f?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script which will check the presence of USB flash drives at any moment. To do so, I'm using the open method with the command `lsusb -f`. It is running fine until after a while, I get the error `too many files open` which I don't know how to cope with it.

```
proc1=os.popen("lsusb -f")
nombre=proc1.read()
proc1.close()
```

I just want to build a list from the `lsusb -f` command and process the data.

Comment: Instead of using `lsusb` at all, you'd do much better to glob the contents of sysfs -- avoiding all the overhead of starting up a subprocess, and the need for file handles connected to its stdin/stdout/stderr (which are what are tripping you up here).

Comment: ...that said, if you *are* going to use a subprocess, you need to be sure to close its file descriptors. Python will eventually garbage-collect them and close them that way, but if you're running a process frequently enough, that GC may not happen fast enough to prevent filling your FD table.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer Charles Duffy. As you said, " i would do much better to glob the contents", how can i do that? Is there another way to get the serial number (which is what i'm looking for when i'm doing the lsusb -f command) of the usb devices?

Comment: `lsusb` gets its data from sysfs, so... well, if it can do it, you can do it yourself. Look for `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb1/serial`, or similar for actual bus location.